# Can't send MMS messages (but can receive)

Tags: mms

About a week ago I lost the ability to send MMS messages. I can still receive, and single-recipient SMS works fine. The phone is a Moto X, stock. I did recently install some new apps; could one of them be interfering with the messaging app?

EDIT: the message I get is `invalid destination address` or `could not send message`.

Comment: Have you checked your MMS APN settings?

Comment: Just did. All that's listed is a single radio button, "Verizon Internet," which is selected.

Comment: You most likely need another for MMS. Best to check with Verizon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This may help
>
> i have test Moto G
>
> 1.Open Message
>
> 2.Choose Attach Option on right side Options(Picture,Capture picture,Videos,Capture Video,Audio,Record audio and Slideshow).
>
> 3.Choose Capture Video/Videos,if choose video then we have send small video otherwise its not selected.
>
> 4.Then last Send MMS.

[image]

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it looks like it _ought_ to work, but as it happens the problem behavior disappeared before I could try it out, and I haven't been able to replicate it since. All very strange.